# "Failed allocate render result, out of memory" on render - Cycles Blender 2.79b

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, error

I am working on a little personnal project which contains two scenes (no animation, just a fixed render). Almost all the assets are linked from other blend files.

Yesterday, I rendered the first scene without problem.
I tried to render the second scene, and there is the problem. The viewport renders the scene just fine, but when I hit the render button, I just get an error message : "Failed allocate render result, out of memory".

I can't get why. It gives me this message on GPU render and CPU as well.

I work on Windows 7 64bits, 8Go RAM, nVidia 1060 gtx 6Go. Blender 2.79b.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys !
I just saw I put "1000 %" on the render size instead of 100% ! That was the cause !